# Empty Index in Gcloud Datastore

Tags: python-3.x, gcloud

I am developing a webapp using python3 and I created this index.yaml

```
indexes:
    - kind: quotation
      properties:
      - name: ref
        direction: asc
      - name: date
        direction: desc
```

But the index is empty:
[image]

Even if I have 1000+ entities in the quotation kind.

What I am missing?

F.

Comment: It could be that the GUI is not showing properly even though the index is correctly set. Have you tried running a query that requires that index in order to check if it's working? You may try `SELECT * FROM quotation WHERE ref = '<INSERT-VALUE>' AND date < <SOME-DATE>
ORDER BY date DESC` from the Datastore GQL query page. The example is adapted from the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/concepts/indexes#index_definition_and_structure). Alternatively do it from Python modifying the query above with Python Datastore query syntax.

Comment: Yes, that was the case. thx!